# How to limit the output of print function with str?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to read a file through the internet using the socket module. And I need to print up to 3000 characters
this is my code

```
import socket 
mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
userurl = input("Ente a URL: ")
lst = userurl.split('/')
host = lst[2]
print(host)
try:
    mysock.connect((host, 80))
except:
    print("Invalid URL")
    exit() 
cmd = f'GET {userurl} HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)
while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if len(data) < 1:
        break                
    print(data.decode(),end='')
mysock.close()
```

I'm limited to print just 3000 characters and I don't know how? and if the data characters are more than 3000, I want to print the first 3000 characters and ignore the rest.

Comment: Instead of *while True* use a *for* loop limited by a range of 3000

Answer (score 0):

If your data is a string, you can use `textwrap.shorten` Python builtin if it is only about displaying a shorted version of your data. The advantage of course is that you can load your whole data once and display only part of it.

Example:

```py
text = """
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
"""

>>> import textwrap

>>> textwrap.shorten(text, 50)
```

Returns

```
'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur [...]'
```

You can check the builtin [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html?highlight=text#module-textwrap).